# Criteria for polynomial to have infinite solutions to $b^n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Say you have a polynomial in x, with the largest exponent of x $\ge$ 2, and an integer. 
(So,
 ${x^2-1}$ fits criteria but,
${x-1}$ does not.)

For simplicity sake I am naming this polynomial a. Does this polynomial have to be expressible in the form 
$$\left(a^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{^n}$$
(So, $x^2+2x+1$ is expressible in this form but $x^2+1$ is not expressible in this form.)

In order to have infinite rational solution to 
$$b^n$$
with b being a non zero rational number. 
Intuitively I am almost certain this is correct but I am not sure how to go about proving it.

Comment: What do you mean expressible as $(a^{1/n})^n$? Isn't that just $a$?

Comment: I think I see what you mean, as $x^2 + 2x + 1 = (x+1)^2$. You should write $a(x)= b(x)^n$ for some polynomial $b(x)$. Now I don't know what you mean by "to have infinite rational solution to $b^n$". What is $b$ in this case and what does it have to with $a$?

Comment: b is a non zero rational number

Comment: a is just what I named any polynomial

Comment: What is a solution to $b^n$?

Comment: $\left(a^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^n$=$b^n$

Comment: You are trying to prove this expression has infinite solutions when b is a non zero rational number, only when a is expressible in the form $\left(a^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{^n}$ ie the nth root of a different polynomial to the n